# Filter pages with dojo/struts2

Tags: java, dojo

I have dojo views eg.: `/app/#dashboard`, `/app/#login` etc..

I would like to write a filter which is navigate back to my `/app/#login` when the user is not authenticated.

The problem is i can't write an url-pattern to the web.xml which can interpret the dojo view's URL after the `#` mark.

So the application is redirecting to the login, and from there again to the login infinitely. If write url pattern eg.: `/app/#dashboard` nothing happens, the filter won't called.

In the filter the url is every time `/app/` without the `#` part.

How can i filter out certain dojo views?

Comment: What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Don't know, i tried a lots of url-patterns. I go through all of the servletcontext properties what can help, but nothing.

Comment: How struts2 is related?

Comment: It's a struts2 wiith dojo project. I search for other solutions too. Tried interceptors, but i think Filters is the right way to achive this.

Comment: But it's not struts2 problem, isn't it? I don't know why you unable to write url, use url tag it can generate dashes

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/2210/struts-2-interceptor-example